# Laravel, Socialite & Middleware Infinite Redirect Loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

I followed the laracasts tutorial on Socialite.  My ultimate aim is to connect to azure ad, but I was having problems with various aspects of that so I thought I'd start with his github tutorial and get it working in principle first.  I was fine until I tried to use middleware - now I get caught in infinite redirect loops.  If I break out of the loop and go to the homepage, it has successfully logged me in - but obviously the user won't know that and will think it's failed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ed.

AuthController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\AuthenticateUser;

class AuthController extends Controller  {

public function login(AuthenticateUser $authenticateUser, Request $request) {
    $authenticateUser->execute($request->has('code'), $this);
    return \Socialite::with('github')->redirect();
}

public function logout() {
    if (\Auth::check()) \Auth::logout(); 
    return view('auth.loggedout');
}   

}
```

AuthenticateUser:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use Request;

class AuthenticateUser {

private $socialite;
private $auth;

public function __construct(UserRepository $users, Socialite $socialite, Guard $auth) {
    $this->users = $users;
    $this->socialite = $socialite;
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

public function execute($hasCode) {

    if (!$hasCode) {
        return $this->getAuthorizationFirst();
    }

    $user = $this->users->findbyEmail($this->getUser());

    $this->auth->login($user, true);

    return redirect('/');
}

public function getAuthorizationFirst() {
    return $this->socialite->driver('github')->redirect();
}

public
        function getUser() {
    return $user = $this->socialite->driver('github')->user();
}

}
```

routes.php:

```
Route::get('o365/connect', 'AuthController@login');        
Route::get('o365/callback', 'AuthController@login');        
Route::get('auth/logout', 'AuthController@logout');
```

Authenticate Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class Authenticate {

/**
 * The Guard implementation.
 *
 * @var Guard
 */
protected $auth;

/**
 * Create a new filter instance.
 *
 * @param  Guard  $auth
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Guard $auth) {
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('o365/connect');
        }
    }

    if (\Auth::check()) {
        return $next($request);
    }        
}
}
```

Comment: While debugging you want to use `dd()` (dump and die) kind of **breakpoints**. When you suspect something is breaking your code dd and see yourself. There can be many reasons why you are in infinite redirect loop and you will most likely solve it by yourself using this technique.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried dd a lot, but since the code is actually working, it's hard to figure out where to do it.  The code actually functions to log me in - it just gets stuck redirecting.